# Locked out of Sharepoint (but I'm admin!)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a Windows Sharepoint Server 2007, running on Windows Server 2003. Very simple domain and I'm the administrator and my main user account is also an admin. Both are listed as collection administrators.

I gave all users in our primary site, read-only permissions since we are migrating to a hosted solution but now I can't get in and do anything. It looks like even Admin is now read-only and no settings page allows me access to change it back.

Any thoughts? thanks.

Comment: You forgot to add "DOH!!!"  Sorry couldn't resist :)

Comment: yeah tell me about it - you'd think that was impossible ... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262811.aspx

```
stsadm -o setsitelock 

   -url <URL name> 

   -lock {none | noadditions | readonly | noaccess}
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you able to get into Central Admin? Is it a particular site collection that is giving you trouble?  What message are you getting?  What happens when you try to modify permissions?

Edit: Man, I wish I could TS into that box and take a look.   If you are having trouble even with the account that installed SharePoint, you are not in a good place :)

Two thoughts: 
1) Using the account that installed SharePoint, on the server run:

`stsadm.exe -o siteowner -url <url of site collection> -ownerlogin DOMAIN\USER`

Maybe try granting site owner permissions to an account other than yours in case something is horked up with your account.  Maybe temporarily create an account just for this purpose.

2) How much stuff is on this site?  I you have read access, you should be able to pull the content/files off and manually move them over to the new hosted site you mentioned.

Comment: Yes I can get into the Central Admin - if I try surf to a page to change permissions I just get Access Denied. Also, all the drop down menus are empty. Its my only site collection.

Comment: @typemismatch: Updated my post with some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Log in as the user account that installed sharepoint if you can.  Are there any errors in the event log?

Comment: yeah that would be administrator - no difference. Tons of errors, which is why we're moving, the system kinda died but permissions were ok until I made that change.

Comment: If you gave all user R/O access you might have shot yourself in the foot.  Note that going to a hosted solution will not resolve issues like this.  Before even thinking about going to a hostd provider I would restore this site from a backup and get folks comfortable using it before adding the expense uf having a hosting provider tell you that when there are issues he's just going to restore the last backup you made (unless he's making backups in which case the last backup he made).